# Error in running a tabs with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have developing my tabs, using only jQuery without other third-party plugins.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $(".resp-tab-content").hide();
  $("ul.resp-tabs-list li:first").addClass("active").show();
  $(".resp-tab-content:first").show();

  $("ul.resp-tabs-list li").click(function()
       {
    $("ul.resp-tabs-list li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".resp-tab-content").hide();

    var activeTab = $(this).find("span").attr("href");
    $(activeTab).fadeIn();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
ul.resp-tabs-list {
    list-style: none;
    background: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #EAEAEA;
}

.resp-tab-item {
    color: #343a4e;
    font-size: .875em;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 .6em .5em;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #FFFFFF;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.resp-tab-active {
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #1ca0de;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #3E9CCA;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
}

.resp-tabs-container {
    padding: 0px;
    clear: left;
    border-top: none;
    background: none;
}

.tab-content {
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #EAEAEA;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="horizontalTab" style="display: block; margin: 0px; width: 100%;">
  <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
    <li class="resp-tab-item resp-tab-active"><span>Today</span></li>
    <li class="resp-tab-item"><span>This Week</span></li>
    <li class="resp-tab-item"><span>This Month</span></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="resp-tabs-container">
    <div class="resp-tab-content resp-tab-content-active" style="display:block"><div class="tab-content">a</div></div>
    <div class="resp-tab-content"><div class="tab-content">b</div></div>
    <div class="resp-tab-content"><div class="tab-content">c</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I took the design from this example that I found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mk3sdn24/1/).

My idea is not to use the label `<a>`, but to use the label `<span>` to show the content of each tabs.

> The error that the code is presenting me, is that when I click on each existing tabs, it does not work for me, the content is not hidden, it is not executed correctly.

I have managed to imitate the design, but it works not, and there is a small error in the design the gray border is on top and not on the text that represents each tabs.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: what is the error you are facing?

Comment: @AravindS Does not show tabs

Comment: Problem is your script dont have the code to not showing resp-tab-content based on click

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try following

- For `li`, the active class is `resp-tab-active` set and reset this
- Remove `display:block` style as it is unnecessary
- Give `ids` to the content divs
- Give `hrefs` to the span elements
- Add `display:flex` to style for `ul.resp-tabs-list`

**Note**, you should not use `href`for span. Use some data attributes instead like `data-tab-id`, etc

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $(".resp-tab-content").hide();
  $("ul.resp-tabs-list li:first").addClass("active").show();
  $(".resp-tab-content:first").show();

  $("ul.resp-tabs-list li").click(function()
       {
    $("ul.resp-tabs-list li").removeClass("resp-tab-active");
    $(this).addClass("resp-tab-active");
    $(".resp-tab-content").hide();

    var activeTab = $(this).find("span").attr("href");
    $(activeTab).fadeIn();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
ul.resp-tabs-list {
    list-style: none;
    background: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #EAEAEA;
}

.resp-tab-item {
    color: #343a4e;
    font-size: .875em;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 .6em .5em;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #FFFFFF;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.resp-tab-active {
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #1ca0de;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #3E9CCA;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
}

.resp-tabs-container {
    padding: 0px;
    clear: left;
    border-top: none;
    background: none;
}

.tab-content {
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #EAEAEA;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="horizontalTab" style="display: block; margin: 0px; width: 100%;">
  <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
    <li class="resp-tab-item resp-tab-active"><span href="#a">Today</span></li>
    <li class="resp-tab-item"><span href="#b">This Week</span></li>
    <li class="resp-tab-item"><span href="#c">This Month</span></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="resp-tabs-container">
    <div id="a" class="resp-tab-content resp-tab-content-active"><div class="tab-content">a</div></div>
    <div id="b" class="resp-tab-content"><div class="tab-content">b</div></div>
    <div id="c" class="resp-tab-content"><div class="tab-content">c</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, friend because the gray border is shown at the top and it is not shown in the same blue border, as the image in my question shows.

Comment: `href` is not a valid attribute for a `span` you would be better off replacing the `span` with `a`, it is a link to another part of the page after all.

Comment: @JonP - Correct. I will add the same in notes. Thanks.

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal it is correct to use this `href` in a tag `<span>`, maybe another attribute should be implemented ?

Comment: @IniDesing.com - You can use it, however, it is not what is meant for. Hence, we should use some other attribute or can you `a` instead if we want to stick to `href` attribute.

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal Use better `var activeTab = $(this).find("span").attr("data-target");`

Comment: @IniDesing.com - Agreed. That is why I have added a note section for the same. Thank you!

Comment: @IniDesing.com no, it is better to use the right tool for the job, which is replacing `span` with `a`, it is after all a link to a location on the same page.

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal the system of tabs, does not work when adding two different tabs in the same page in spite of existing its own identifier does not work when adding two columns in each column a tabs with different data, if one executes the other executes in spite of changing its identifier in the HTML.

Comment: @Ana - Do you mean that the code fails when there are 2 tab groups on the page?

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal friend, because the different identifier does not work, when adding more than one tabs in different columns of the website design, where each tabs has different information?

Comment: @Ana - I am not able to understand your problem. Can you please replicate the issue somewhere?

Comment: Note, in case of 2 tab groups you need to make sure you are applying / removing classes from the right group. In the earlier case, you were doing that independent of the group. But using `siblings` and `parent` function, we have confined it to the working group only.

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal thanks friend, sorry for the problems caused, I thought that just changing the values of the HTML identifier would work :(

Comment: @Ana - No problem. Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

- You have done it in the wrong way. You added the wrong `active` class
  `resp-tab-active`
- Instead of using `href` in `span`, use `data-target` to the target `li`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $(".resp-tab-content").hide();
  $("ul.resp-tabs-list li:first").addClass("resp-tab-active").show();
  $(".resp-tab-content:first").show();

  $("ul.resp-tabs-list li").click(function(){
    $("ul.resp-tabs-list li").removeClass("resp-tab-active");
    $(this).addClass("resp-tab-active");
    $(".resp-tab-content").hide();

    var activeTab = $(this).find("span").attr("data-target");
    $(activeTab).fadeIn();
    //return false;
  });
});
```

```css
ul.resp-tabs-list {
    list-style: none;
    background: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #EAEAEA;
}

.resp-tab-item {
    color: #343a4e;
    font-size: .875em;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 .6em .5em;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #FFFFFF;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.resp-tab-active {
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #1ca0de;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #3E9CCA;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
}

.resp-tabs-container {
    padding: 0px;
    clear: left;
    border-top: none;
    background: none;
}

.tab-content {
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #EAEAEA;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="horizontalTab" style="display: block; margin: 0px; width: 100%;">
  <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
    <li class="resp-tab-item resp-tab-active">
        <span data-target="#first">Today</span>
    </li>
    <li class="resp-tab-item">
       <span data-target="#second">This Week</span>
    </li>
    <li class="resp-tab-item">
       <span data-target="#third">This Month</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="resp-tabs-container">
    <div class="resp-tab-content" id="first">
      <div class="tab-content">a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="resp-tab-content" id="second">
      <div class="tab-content">b</div>
    </div>
    <div class="resp-tab-content" id="third">
      <div class="tab-content">c</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The system of tabs, does not work to have more than two tabs on the same page, I'm trying to add two different columns of my web design two different tabs, despite having identifiers porpios does not work, you can observe the following code to Although it is different to the code that you public, but the same happens with your code like the others.

Comment: I watched friend jsfiddle.net/Ldzcn87e/9

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS class for hide/active of the content.
Add/remove class on basis of tab selection.

```js
 $(".resp-tab-item").click(function(ev) {
     var activeClass = $(".resp-tab-item.resp-tab-active");
     activeClass.removeClass("resp-tab-active");
     var target;
     if (ev.target == this) {
         target = ev.target;
     } else {
         target = ev.target.parentElement;
     }
     $(target).addClass("resp-tab-active");
     var count = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(target.parentElement.children, target);
     var activeTabC = $(".resp-tab-content.resp-tab-content-active");
     activeTabC.removeClass("resp-tab-content-active");
     activeTabC.addClass("resp-tab-content-hide");
     var tabNeedToActive = $($(".resp-tab-content")[count]);
     tabNeedToActive.removeClass("resp-tab-content-hide");
     tabNeedToActive.addClass("resp-tab-content-active");


 });
```

```css
ul.resp-tabs-list {
    list-style: none;
    background: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #EAEAEA;
}

.resp-tab-item {
    color: #343a4e;
    font-size: .875em;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 .6em .5em;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #FFFFFF;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.resp-tab-active {
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #1ca0de;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #3E9CCA;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
}

.resp-tabs-container {
    padding: 0px;
    clear: left;
    border-top: none;
    background: none;
}

.tab-content {
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #EAEAEA;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.resp-tab-content-hide {
  display : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="horizontalTab" style="display: block; margin: 0px; width: 100%;">
  <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
    <li class="resp-tab-item resp-tab-active">
      <span>Today</span>
    </li>
    <li class="resp-tab-item">
      <span>This Week</span>
    </li>
    <li class="resp-tab-item">
      <span>This Month</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="resp-tabs-container">
    <div class="resp-tab-content resp-tab-content-active">
      <div class="tab-content">a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="resp-tab-content resp-tab-content-hide">
      <div class="tab-content">b</div>
    </div>
    <div class="resp-tab-content resp-tab-content-hide">
      <div class="tab-content">c</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The system of tabs, does not work to have more than two tabs on the same page, I'm trying to add two different columns of my web design two different tabs, despite having identifiers porpios does not work, you can observe the following code to Although it is different to the code that you public, but the same happens with your code like the others.

Comment: I watched friend jsfiddle.net/Ldzcn87e/9

Answer (score 0):

As I consider no other answer has addressed this properly, I will.

You should be using [links (`<a>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) instead of `span`. It is semantically the right choice you are creating a link to another location on the page - the target tag.

Further more don't target the `li` for the event handler target the link itself, then you can access the `href` attribute directly

**EDIT** Code has been modified to support multi tabs.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $(".resp-tab-content").hide();
  $("ul.resp-tabs-list li:first").addClass("active").show();
  /*Folling line changed to support multi tabs*/
  $(".resp-tabs-container .resp-tab-content:first-child").show();

  $("ul.resp-tabs-list a").click(function()
       {
    $("ul.resp-tabs-list li").removeClass("resp-tab-active");
    $(this).parent("li").addClass("resp-tab-active");
    /*Following line removed to support multi tabs
    $(".resp-tab-content").hide();
    */

    var activeTab = $(this).attr("href");
    /*Folliwng line added to support multi tabs*/
    $(activeTab).siblings(".resp-tab-content").hide();
    $(activeTab).fadeIn();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
ul.resp-tabs-list {
    list-style: none;
    background: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #EAEAEA;
}

.resp-tab-item {
    color: #343a4e;
    font-size: .875em;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*padding: 0 .6em .5em;  MOVE THIS TO THE A Style*/
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    /*float: left; - Don't need this with Flexbox*/
    border-bottom: solid 1px #FFFFFF;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.resp-tab-item a, .resp-tab-item a:visited, .resp-tab-item a:active, .resp-tab-item a:hover {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #343a4e; 
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 .6em .5em; /*Move from LI style*/
  display:inline-block; /*Makes vertical padding meaningful*/
}

.resp-tab-active {
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #1ca0de;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #3E9CCA;
    /*padding-bottom: .5em;*/
}

.resp-tabs-container {
    padding: 0px;
    clear: left;
    border-top: none;
    background: none;
}

.tab-content {
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #EAEAEA;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="horizontalTab" style="display: block; margin: 0px; width: 100%;">
  <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
    <li class="resp-tab-item resp-tab-active"><a href="#a">Today</a></li>
    <li class="resp-tab-item"><a href="#b">This Week</a></li>
    <li class="resp-tab-item"><a href="#c">This Month</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="resp-tabs-container">
    <div id="a" class="resp-tab-content resp-tab-content-active"><div class="tab-content">a</div></div>
    <div id="b" class="resp-tab-content"><div class="tab-content">b</div></div>
    <div id="c" class="resp-tab-content"><div class="tab-content">c</div></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="horizontalTab2" style="display: block; margin: 0px; width: 100%;">
  <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
    <li class="resp-tab-item resp-tab-active"><a href="#aa">Today</a></li>
    <li class="resp-tab-item"><a href="#bb">This Week</a></li>
    <li class="resp-tab-item"><a href="#cc">This Month</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="resp-tabs-container">
    <div id="aa" class="resp-tab-content resp-tab-content-active"><div class="tab-content">aa</div></div>
    <div id="bb" class="resp-tab-content"><div class="tab-content">bb</div></div>
    <div id="cc" class="resp-tab-content"><div class="tab-content">cc</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The system of tabs, does not work to have more than two tabs on the same page, I'm trying to add two different columns of my web design two different tabs, despite having identifiers porpios does not work, you can observe the following code to Although it is different to the code that you public, but the same happens with your code like the others.

Comment: I watched friend jsfiddle.net/Ldzcn87e/9

Comment: Please just ask one question at a time. The answer provided fits the answer you have asked originally. If you have new requirements, accept an appropriate answer then ask a new question.

Answer (score -4):

place JQuery script at the bottom of the code.